# Multiline UILabel in a UITableViewCell giving the wrong height with autoLayout in iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I've been reading other people solutions that I found here for cells with dynamic height and multiline labels but none of them seem to be working 100%.

The Cell has the following vertical constraints:[Vertical cell constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2at3.png)

The tableView is configured as:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

In the method tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: I'm setting the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the multiline label:

```
JBLabelTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JBLabelTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *labelText = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
[cell.bodyLabel setText:labelText];
CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), 99999);
[cell setBounds:cellFrame];
cell.contentView.bounds = cell.bounds;
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
[cell.bodyLabel setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:CGRectGetWidth(cell.bodyLabel.frame)];
return cell;
```

The dataSource is setup with this two strings:

```
_items = @[@"On this screen you can see the groups of people that you have set yourself up to chat with.\n\nCommunities are groups of people that are created for you on the basis of your interests, and how you feel about your condition, or the conditions of those you care about.\n\nThey are not only there to provide you with help or someone to talk to but can also benefit from the help and support that you can give.",
               @"On this screen you can see a list of the conversations that you are involved in.\n\nWithin conversations you can ask questions to like-minded people or just have someone to chat to. These are places where you can help someone or get someone to help you."];
```

Running the project in an iPhone 6 simulator, the first string gets its last line cut-off:[iPhone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LALvF.png)

The constraints between all the objects look right but the calculated height for the multiline label is not not right for the first string.

Has anyone run into this issue and have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I have also tried to do the iOS6 and iOS7 way returning the cell height in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: `[cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]`

Comment: You could keep and update a constraint on the `bodyLabel height` that is set to `sizeThatFits:` whenever the text is changed

Comment: Thanks @kdogisthebest, I just tried your suggestion and the result is the same. It looks to me that any function of the framework that calculates the height of a label is giving a shorter height in some occasions for multiline labels (I have also tried the NSString method: `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is probably correct.i just added this two line (not necessary to say. from the look of your screenshots you already added!)

```
cell. bodyLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell. bodyLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Its seems that your problem lay in your user interface. This is the user interface that i used for UITableViewCell and it worked perfectly fine
[image]

**UPDATE!**

just add this to your viewDidLoad [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; [self.view setNeedsLayout]; 
in viewDidLoad the frame of user interface is being used and you need to update the constraint and view to use the device screen frame The sequence of layoutIfNeeded and setNeedsLayout is important. you need to first call layoutIfNeeded.

Comment: The issue is not occurring always, it depends on the screen size and string size. Also if the font type/size and constraints are different than mine then it might not reproduce. I have similar constraints in my project. I'm sharing here a link to the sample project I used in case anyone wants to take a look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gpjcdny50m37on3/label.zip?dl=0

Comment: just add this to your viewDidLoad 
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
in viewDidLoad the frame of user interface is being used and you need to update the constraint and view to use the device screen frame

The sequence of layoutIfNeeded and setNeedsLayout is important. you need to first call layoutIfNeeded

Comment: Thanks @user962913 adding those two lines to the viewDidLoad does fix the problem. You could update your answer with the fix so other people could find the solution faster.